# Sum orders of $4,(\omega+1),(\omega+7)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First experiences with set theory. The exercise request find the sum order of $4,(\omega+1),(\omega+7)$ so that it'll be the smallest/greatest. Here my solutions:

> $4+(\omega+1)+(\omega+7) = \omega+\omega+7$
>
> $4+(\omega+7)+(\omega+1)= \omega+\omega+1\rightarrow$ **Smallest**
>
> $(\omega+1)+4+(\omega+7) = \omega+\omega+7$
>
> $(\omega+1)+(\omega+7)+4 = \omega+\omega+11\rightarrow$ **Greatest**
>
> $(\omega+7)+(\omega+1)+4 = \omega+\omega+5$
>
> $(\omega+7)+4+(\omega+1) = \omega+\omega+1 \rightarrow$ **Smallest**

Is this right? Can someone check if there are some mistakes?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any $\omega$ is going to swallow anything finite that comes before it. So the result is always going to be
$$
\omega + \omega + (\text{whatever finite stuff comes after the last }\omega)
$$
So yeah, those look right to me.